# Modelling the magnetic field between repelling magnets when the permeability between them changes

Tags: magnetic-fields

Imagine two drilled magnets threaded onto a frictionless upright shaft, set N-N. One fixed down, the other floating above.

Now, if I move an iron gate in and out of the gap (the shaft has a gap), the upper magnet will move down and up.

How would you express the force exerted on the iron gate by the magnets, on the in and out strokes?

Comment: It’s gone a bit quiet. Is there no easy answer, or could I phrase the question better?